# Which Indian female boxers' stories was "Saala Khadoos" inspired from?

Tags: saala-khadoos

The climax of [Saala Khadoos](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5310090/) shows that it was inspired through real-life stories of some Indian female boxers who have won the Common Wealth games.

So, **is the story inspired from the life events of one/some specific boxers**, or is it a generalization of Indian female boxing scenario?

**If the former, then who are those boxers?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sudha Kongara, the director and script writer of Saala Khadoos, wrote about the sports drama about the North Chennai and its boxing culture. She gathered information about female boxers and took help of athletes including [Mary Kom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Kom) to form the story of this movie.

There were rumors that this movie is a biopic of Mary Kom. Some reports also suggested that this movie is loosely based on the life of Boxing icon [Mohammed Ali Qamar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammed_Ali_Qamar), who was the first Indian to win a gold medal in boxing at the Commonwealth Games, but it was declined.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irudhi_Suttru)

Comment: It is not Muhammad Ali (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Ali). It is Mohammed Ali Qamar (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammed_Ali_Qamar)